# Probability: Expectation of a function.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I've got a probability question where E(x)=5 , Var(x)=36 and Y = 0.7X + 2.

I need to determine the variance of Y using E(Y^2) and [E(Y)]^2.

I just can't figure out how to work out E(Y^2).

I can do it with the (a^2)*Var(x) formula but I'm not sure if I'm meant to use it or not.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does $X\sim(5,36)$ mean? Are you saying $\mathbb{E}(X)=5$ and $\mathbb{Var}(X)=36$?

Comment: Yeah sorry should have made that clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

What is $Y^2$?
$$
Y^2=(0.7X+2)^2=0.49X^2+2.8X+4.
$$
So,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=0.49\mathbb{E}[X^2]+2.8\mathbb{E}[X]+4.
$$
Of course, to finish this, you need to know $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$; however, you can figure this out from knowing both $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\text{Var}[X]$.

Comment: @Steve: In case you are still stuck, E[$X^2$] = ǝuo-ʎʇxıs

Comment: Is there a way to determine E[X^2] without knowing Var(X)?

Comment: @Steve Not without more information about the distribution than you've been given.  If you knew the distribution, then of course you could compute it directly.  However, with the given information, your best bet is to notice that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\text{Var}[X]+(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, you've been a great help.